# Bash script condition for json response

Tags: arrays, json, bash

This script should alert me in case of an error response.

**Issue:** Even when it executes successfully I am getting the email.

**Bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 http://this.url/?parm=1\&par=2)
IFS=\" read __ KEY __ MESSAGE __ <<< "$DATA"
if [[ $KEY == Success ]]; then
    echo something
else
    send email on failure
fi
```

**Response on**

```
Failure:  {"ErrorCode":"11","ErrorMessage":"random message as per error code"}
Sucess:   {"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success"}
```

**This worked finally -**

```
 #!/bin/bash
    DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 http://this.url/?parm=1\&par=2)
    MESSAGE=$(jq '.ErrorMessage' <<< "$DATA")
if [[ "$MESSAGE" == '"Success"' ]] ;  then
echo something
else
send email
fi
```

Comment: Are you sure the variable `$KEY` is equal to the string `Success` ? try putting `echo "$KEY"` right before your `if` test

Comment: No, $KEY = ErrorCode. What variable will be for 11 and 000 ?

Comment: Then that's the cause of your error : you are not reading the good json field. On the other hand, to extract data from a properly fromated json message, `jq` would be the right tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper tool to address your issue would be `jq` :

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 http://this.url/?parm=1\&par=2)
KEY=$(jq -r '.ErrorCode' <<< "$DATA")
MESSAGE=$(jq -r '.ErrorMessage' <<< "$DATA")
if [[ "$KEY" = "000" ]]
then 
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Note : the `-r` flag for `jq` removes the double quotes

Comment: I am getting:  syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""7"") for response "ErrorCode":"7",

Comment: what is the content of `$DATA` ?

Comment: {"ErrorCode":"7","ErrorMessage":"Invalid username / password or Api Key","JobId":null,"MessageData":null}

Comment: right, that's because `-eq` is the integer comparison operator, my bad. You should use the string comparison one. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=$(wget --timeout 5 -O - -q -t 1 http://this.url/?parm=1\&par=2)
KEY=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -oP '"ErrorCode":"\K(\d+)"')
MESSAGE=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -oP '"ErrorMessage":"\K(.+?)(?=")')
((KEY == 0)) && echo success || echo "$MESSAGE"
```

Comment: Analyzing data with tools that are not context aware for structured languages (xml, html, json, yaml, ...) is usually considered [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and can lead to security flaws when ecountering non specific input

Comment: This is just a code sample. The actual api may be more complex. What if there are several, nested error codes ?

Comment: This is the output of the api posted by OP: {"ErrorCode":"7","ErrorMessage":"Invalid username / password or Api Key","JobId":null,"MessageData":null} and my code can't fail on it.